# Ubuntu etcd.service start failed with (code = exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Tags: ubuntu, etcd, systemctl

When I have written my `etcd.service` file, and run with the `systemctl start etcd.service` command, it gives this error:

```
etcd.service - ve489 etcd service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/etcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-06-18 20:59:50 PDT; 3s ago
       Docs: https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd
    Process: 13415 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/etcd --name ubuntu20 --data-dir /var/lib/etcd --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://192.168.159.128:2380 --listen-peer-urls http://192.168.159.128:2380 --listen-client-urls http://192.168.159.128:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379 --advertise-client-urls http://192.168.159.128:2379 --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 --initial-cluster etcd-1=http://192.168.159.128:2380,etcd-2=http://192.168.159.129:2380 --initial-cluster-state new --heartbeat-interval 1000 --election-timeout 5000 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 13415 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

And the source code in the file `etcd.service` is

```
[Unit]
Description=ve489 etcd service
Documentation=https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd
 
[Service]
User=root
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/etcd \
 --name ubuntu20 \
 --data-dir /var/lib/etcd \
 --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://192.168.159.128:2380 \
 --listen-peer-urls http://192.168.159.128:2380 \
 --listen-client-urls http://192.168.159.128:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379 \
 --advertise-client-urls http://192.168.159.128:2379 \
 --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \
 --initial-cluster etcd-1=http://192.168.159.128:2380,etcd-2=http://192.168.159.129:2380 \
 --initial-cluster-state new \
 --heartbeat-interval 1000 \
 --election-timeout 5000
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the `journalctl -xe` command gives this:

```
Jun 18 21:03:57 ubuntu systemd[1]: etcd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit etcd.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Jun 18 21:03:57 ubuntu systemd[1]: etcd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit etcd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 18 21:03:57 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start ve489 etcd service.
-- Subject: A start job for unit etcd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit etcd.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 38547 and the job result is failed.
```

I am a new guy to get in touch with `etcd` so I have no idea what was wrong, can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

I hava the same problem。this is my solution。

first stop etcd service using systemctl

```
systemctl stop etcd.service
```

and then， check port is occupied

```
lsof -i:2380
```

if occupied kill the pid

```
kill -9 xxx
```

last，start etcd service

```
systemctl start etcd.service
```